# Cannot start Chrome in dev mode from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-devtools

When trying to start a Chrome browser in dev mode from Eclipse (launcher type "Launch Chrome), I get the following error message in a window:

"Error Launching Application"

"Could not launch browser - process terminated while trying to connect. Try closing any running Chrome instances.."

That's all. There is nothing in the Eclipse error log or consoles and the suggestion has no effect.

Does anybody know of a way I can get a more detailed error message, if not a solution, can I kick this off from a console, for instance? Thank you.

Comment: Check the OS process list for any leftover chrome processes. Try to [enable logging](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282) and/or use a tool like Process Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

first set your default browser in eclipse as chrome -

path for that is as follows - in eclipse  go to

Windows --> browser --> chrome

Then on your application, right click

Run as --> run on server  (chose any server of your choice )

This should directly open in chrome .

Also please make sure in your chrome you have this plugin added - GWT dev mode.

It is called as - Super Dev Mode, and it is supported in chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gwt-super-dev-button/piekceemifgeaigkimahdckfcikpmleh?hl=en